# Why can't I search this room name in rooms list here?

Tags: support, chat, search

I can search all other rooms (which I usually go to chat) in the Stack Exchange chat [list of all rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=active) except for "[Sandbox/Trash Bin/Something](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1196/sandbox-trash-bin-something)".

Is it because it contains slashes and the search script fails to execute?

Comment: Vikas, your last two edits aren't helpful; but keep them if you wish. The answer at the duplicate does answer this question; unless you simply want "No" for an answer.

Comment: @Rob I wanted to be as original as possible, because if I really knew it was MSE's chat room, I wouldn't even need to ask this question. The problem here is, I didn't know it's MSE room. That's why I rolled it back. If I add MSE, it means I have some idea already that why is it behaving like this.

Comment: As you wish, but you knew that the URLs were for completely different websites; you simply thought one website would search another - got it

Comment: @Rob in short, I wasn't focusing on any url. I've just bookmarked the chat.stackexchange.com and I would search rooms there. I wanted to chat in Sandbox/Trash too, so I searched but couldn't find. It looked very strange and I thought it could be because of those slashes, because all other rooms didn't have slashes.